# Absurd Operation

Tags: click, panel

Under Visual Studio in C# I have been using a class inherited from Panel to simulate a button for years. Now in a Panel this class reacts correctly to the mouse passenger but when I click on it, this Panel goes to the top left and I have to click a second time to close this Panel! The other Panels work perfectly. What can happen? Thank you for your ideas.
If I use the very ugly Button from VS everything is fine though!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.